# Show Non English text in scenic

Tags: elixir

I tried to show Persian text by `text primitive` in a Scenic app but Scenic showed some boxes with `X` inside them!
I tried use font but I wasn't successful.

This is my code:

```
g
|> text("متن نمونه", t: {0, 700}, fill: :white, font: @font_hash)
```

Should I make an issue in their GitHub or there is a solution?

Thanks for your help.

## Update:

I followed [instructions for custom fonts](https://github.com/boydm/scenic#custom-fonts) to cache font metrics (thanks to [Aleksei Matiushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/aleksei-matiushkin)) then I got another problem that shown in this picture:

[image: Wrong Persian form]

That text should be like this:

[image: correct Persian form]

In Persian, some letters in a word may connect to other letters. In these cases those letters are displayed by a different character.
(The problem here is that all letters are displayed in their standalone format. Also, the text direction is wrong)

For example:
The correct writing for word "Hello" is "سلام" but in the text it is displayed like "م‌ا‌ل‌س". It's kinda like displaying "Hello World" as "dlroW olleH"

Maybe the encoding is the problem which I could not find a way to try UTF-8. Or it might be the text direction...

Comment: Have you followed the [instructions for custom fonts](https://github.com/boydm/scenic#custom-fonts)?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks. Post updated.

Comment: Could you please describe the issue in plain words for those who unfortunately cannot read Persian?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I updated Post again. Thanks for your notice.

Answer (score 0):

Totally understand the issue. The problem is that the font rendering engine is quite simplistic at this time and doesn't support right-to-left, up-down, character clusters, automatic ligatures, etc.

The simplistic font rendering is one of the reasons it is < 1.0. Would love to move off the old-school character atlas technique it currently uses and toward something based on the GPU (Slug). That would make these issues much easier, but isn't very compatible with an open source project.

If your need is strong enough, I could add right-to-left, but it isn't easy.